# Ant file copy not working with jdk 7

Tags: java, ant, javac

We are noticing some weird behaviour with ant when we moved the jdk version from 1.6 to 1.7. In our ant file, we have a target which copies some files from one directory to another directory. This works fine as far as we are using jdk 1.6. But the moment we start this using jdk 7, it complains about read only permission

`Failed to copy /path/to/source/file.js to /path/to/destination/file.js due to can't write to read-only destination file /path/to/destination/file.js`

The ant  version is 1.8.2 and below is the ant target which is under question

```
<target name="copyfiles">         
    <mkdir dir="${env.TARGET_ROOT}/destination"/>
    <copy file="etc/file.js" todir="${env.TARGET_ROOT}/destination" overwrite="true" verbose="true"/>
</target>
```

This code works fine with java_home = /usr/j2sdk1.6.0_45 but fails with java_home = j2sdk1.7.0_25_x86_64

Any idea what is going wrong ? Is it 32 bit vs 64 bit problem ? Is there a difference in which jdk 6 and jdk 7 are consumed in ant ?

Any help would be really appreciable

Comment: what are you doing just before? it does not have sense if you are using the same user.

Answer (score 1):

Try using copy task's attribute `force` (Description at [Copy's attribs](http://ant.apache.org/manual/Tasks/copy.html))